# can Autofac search for string dependencies in AppConfig

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

is it possible to make autofac fetch for string dependencies in `AppConfig`/`WebConfig`?
I've got some configuration stuff like `ConnectionString` in `WebConfig` and I'd like to have autofac fetch it from there and resolve dependencies that refer to it.

Comment: You can read it yourself using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it during [Activation](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OnActivatingActivated) events. Or you can read it before registering, and use a code block to do the registration. Or you can build a [module](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules) and isolate the complex registration conditionals.